# loop index comparison is not assembled as expected

Tags: c, for-loop, assembly, x86, gdb

I'm trying to understand C using GDB, the program I'm debugging is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < 10; i++) {
      puts("Hello, world!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I debug it I see that in assembly the value of i is compared to 10 and not 9, I think it's supposed to be compared to 9 since I'm not including 10 in my loop interval. This is the GDB output:

```
(gdb) x/i $rip
=> 0x100000f36 <main+22>:   cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0xa
```

**The value pointed to by rbp-0x8 is the i value and rbp-0x8 now equals 0 as expected**

Comment: Why do you think it would compare to 9? 10 is not in the loop interval but it is the value you are explicitly comparing in the for loop.

Comment: Check the following jump instruction.

Comment: Because the upper bound of the loop is 9 not 10, as 10 is not included in the loop period

Comment: the loop exits if i >= 10. What is not to understand?

Comment: the jump is probably JAE. "Jump on greater or equal" and exits the loop

Comment: the next jump command checks for greater than or equal to, do in that way it includes 10. the GDB output is:
0x100000f3d <main+29>: jge    0x100000f62 <main+66>

Comment: I thought it was supposed to be cmp DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 0x9. As I find it in the book "Hacking the art of exploitation" page 32. He's debugging the same code. but the following jump command checks for less than or equal to: jle 0x8048393 <main+31>

Comment: There is no "supposed to be" here with respect to details of machine instructions.  The compiler can write machine code for your loop any way it wishes, so long as it produces the behavior required by C.  For example, it could completely unroll your loop and optimize out `i` altogether.

Comment: What code do you actually expect? And how does the generated code **functionally** differ from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow) regarding the `cmp` instruction:

> Performs a comparison operation between arg1 and arg2. The comparison
>   is performed by a (signed) subtraction of arg2 from arg1, the results
>   of which can be called Temp. Temp is then discarded. If arg2 is an
>   immediate value it will be sign extended to the length of arg1. The
>   EFLAGS register is set in the same manner as a sub instruction.

So the `cmp` instruction sets a flag if the left value is less than, greater than, or equal to the right value.  If you check the next instruction, you'll probably find that it's `jge`, meaning it jumps out of the loop if `i <= 10`

Comment: That is just for x86. Other CPUs might not even have a CMP instruction.

Comment: No it makes a lot of sense, in my case after comparing to the index if greater than or equal to it will leave the loop, otherwise it will continue executing the loop. But in the other case I was confused with GDB was comparing to 9 then if it's less than or equal to it would keep executing the loop till it's not then it jumps to the end of the loop

Comment: Yes Olaf I'm talking about x86 in that case

Comment: I explained it in the answers, I wonder why it is not accepted nor get vote.. It seems sometimes being fast is everything...
And I wasn't (a little!)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the next instruction is jump if equal or greater `jge`.
Compilers usually do these kinds of changes. There is nothing to worry about. For example in this case compiler change the (human expected)"jump to the loop head" to "jump out of the loop". I assume it is better to compile a code to the first kind, in order to make the optimization step easier.

If it was compared with 9, the next instruction would be jump if not lower or equal `jnle`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are starting at 0. 0, the lowest limit is the first element in the loop and 9, the uppermost limit is the tenth. Hence i is compared to 10.

If you do i=1, i<=10, then you will get what you desire. Although both these approaches mean the same.

I hope this helps.